# How to update SQL query with ID reference from other table?

Tags: mysql

I have table A:

```
id   name    product_id    shipped
1    Apple      10           100
2    Orange     11           110
3    Banana     12           0
4    Mango      13           0
```

And Table B:

```
id  product_id   qty   order_id
1      10        100     2
2      11        110     2
3      12        120     3
4      13        130     2
```

I need to update the quantity

```
UPDATE table_B SET qty=0 WHERE order_id=2 
AND table_B.product_id = table_A.product_id
```

The table_A.product_id is get from a script. How can I do this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE table_B b
LEFT JOIN table_A a 
ON b.product_id = a.product_id 
SET b.qty= 0 WHERE b.order_id=2
```